# using json to object binding in asp.net mvc2

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to bind a JSON stringified object to a model and few other strings in the controller and it is not working.

is it not possible,

```
$.ajax({
url: "/SrcManager/AddDataSource",
type: "POST",
data: JSON.stringify({
    content: ct,
    dataSourceName: $("#dataSrcName").val(),
    parameters: parametersCollection,
    sourceContentId: sourceContentId,
    sourceId: null,
    type: contType
}),
success: function (data) {
    if (data.length > 1)
    {
        alert("DataSource Saved Successfully");
        $("#dataSrcId").val(data);
    }
}
});
```

> and var parametersCollection = [];
>
> function IPParameters(paramName, paramValue) {
>       this.ParamName = paramName;
>       this.ParamValue = paramValue; }

```
*** action method : public string AddDataSource(ContentModel scvm){.........}
```

Why does the above not work. Is this not supported or any mistake in the code, kindly suggest the right way.

In the ContentModel, i map the parameters to `List<Parameters>`.

I have added the `JsonValueProviderFactory` also in `global.asax`.

The C# model is :

```
public class SourceContentViewModel
{
    public string sourceId { get; set; }

    public string dataSourceName { get; set; }

    public string sourceContentId { get; set; }

    public string content { get; set; }

    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<Parameters> parameters { get; set; }

    public SourceContentViewModel()
    {
        parameters = new List<Parameters>();
    }
}

public class Parameters
{
    public string ParamName { get; set; }
    public string ParamValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your action method and the javascript you use to send that data?

Comment: @Jan: i have updated the question itself

Comment: Can you show how the ContentModel class is defined? Your question is about modelbinding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send JSON to an ASP.NET MVC 2 application as there is no JSON provider factory out-of-the-box that will allow you to read the request. It is built in ASP.NET MVC 3. You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) and include the `JsonValueProviderFactory` discussed there. Then you will be able to send JSON requests to your ASP.NET MVC 2 controller actions after registering it:

```
protected void Application_Start() 
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
}
```

Also notice the `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` setting when sending the request which instructs the binder that you are sending a JSON request.

Comment: Pls take a look at the updated question. this was working fine sometime back.. but something messed up now..

Comment: @saravanan, no, it's impossible that this has ever worked in an ASP.NET MVC 2 application. Out of the box it doesn't support JSON requests. You are using `JSON.stringify` in your AJAX request which serializes the object into a JSON string. Maybe before you didn't have this JSON.stringify call?

Comment: Adding this to the ajax request fixed the issue. `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`. Thanks Darin Dimitrov.

Comment: @saravanan, if this is working in an ASP.NET MVC 2 application it is because you must have registered a `JsonValueProviderFactory` as shown in my answer.

Comment: I did register the `JsonValueProviderFactory` in the global.asax. you are right. but forgot the contenttype in ajax call.